# Sending a window toback with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, xhtml

I have a program that creates a report from a parent window viewed in a browser.    The report is displayed in a second window.   When I create the report in javascript, the report window appears behind the parent window.   I've tried giving the report window the focus specifying the body tag as follows:

```
body onload='self.focus()';>
```

I've also tried blurring the parent window (and doing both techniques in combination).   But what happens is the parent window stays on top, and the report window appears behind it.   Is there some way to bring the report window to the front after it is generated from the parent?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you create the report window?

Comment: Note that you may be seeing a *browser* artifact - some pop-up blockers can be set to "open pop-ups in the background" or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change

```
body onload='self.focus()';>
```

to

```
body onload='self.focus();'>
```

also just like RoToRa said, How do you create your child window?